# Is the JIRA Issue Collector useful for collecting UI feedback? If so, any best practices?

Tags: feedback, user-feedback

In my company we use JIRA issues in each product function to track and manage our work. The UI designers also use this on a daily basis. While exploring, I came across a feature called Issue Collector. Quick demo here https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VplPRpmeJys

I was wondering if this has been used by anyone to collect feedback on design. It seems primitive but since it is integrated with JIRA, I am hopeful that someone has found a sophisticated way to use it.

If not, please suggest your favorite tool.

Comment: Questions about implementation and tools aren't suited to this site.  If you have a general UX question on collecting feedback, then feel free to ask that instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will give you feedback on everything if it is supplied to the users. Expect bug reports, support tickets to go through this as well. I is likely also ideal to have some sort of human confirmation when dealing with feedback forms, as bots can spam such forms.

As to your question, while JIRA has a ton of plugins I've never used this one. I do however think that this will create quite an overhead as the designers will have to filter and read the feedback to extract the good from the bad. You can still use JIRA for feedback repository by creating a project and entering the feedback yourselves. It takes close to no time and works like a charm.